# DDD: Modeling M:N relation between two roots where the relation itself carries semantic meaning

Tags: oop, architecture, domain-driven-design

**Update** Edited to reflect clarifications requested by Chris Holmes below.  Originally I was referring to a Terminal as a Site but changed it to better reflect my actual domain.

At heart, I think this is a question about modeling a many to many relationship between two root entities where the relationship itself carries some semantic meaning.

In my domain

- You can think of a Terminal as a branch location of our company
- A Terminal can have a relationship with any number of customers
- A customer can have a relationship with any number of terminals (standard many to many)
- A customer\terminal relationship means that a customer can potentially store products at the Terminal
- This relationship can be enabled\disabled.  To be disabled merely means you are temporarily not allowed to store product, so a disabled relationship is different from no relationship at all.
- A customer can have many Offices
- A Terminal that has a relationship with a customer (enabled or not) must have a default office for that customer that they communicate with
- There are some default settings that are applied to all transactions between a Customer and a Terminal, these are set up on a Terminal-Customer Relationship level

I think my objects here are pretty clear, **Terminal**, **Customer**, **Office**, and **TerminalCustomerRelationship** (since there is information being stored specifically about the relationship such as whether it is enabled, default office, ad default settings). Through multiple refactorings I have determined that both Terminal and Customer should probably be aggregate roots. This leaves me with the question of how to design my TerminalCustomerRelationship object to relate the two.

I suppose I could make the traversal from Terminal to TerminalCustomerRelationship unidirectional toward the relationship but I don't know how to break the relation from the relationship to the customer, especially since it needs to contain a reference to an Office which has a relationship to a Customer.

I'm new to this stuff and while most of DDD makes perfect sense I'm getting confused and need a fresh outlook. Can someone give me their opinion on how to deal with this situation?

Please note that I say Relationship not relation.  In my current view it deserves to be an object in the same way that a Marriage would be an object in an application for a wedding chapel.  Its most visible purpose is that it relates two objects, but it has other properties that rightfully belong to it as well.

Answer (score 2):

By your description, you definitely need a "**TerminalCustomerRelationship**" entity to track the associated information.  I would also convert the '**IsEnabled**' flag into a first class 'Event' entity with a timestamp - this gives you the ability to save a history of the state changes (a more realistic view of what's happening in the domain.)

Here's a [sample application](http://www.evolving-software.co.uk/downloads/stack-overflow-654586-ddd-modeling-sample.zip) (in VS2008) that refects your problem. You can tweak/test the code until the relationships make sense.  Run "*bin/debug/TerminalSampleApp.exe*" and right-click "*Terminal->Create Example*" to get started.

Let me know if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Names can often clarify an object's responsibilities and bring a domain model into focus.

I am unclear what a Site is and that makes the entire model confusing, which makes it difficult for me to offer better advice. If a Site were a Vendor, for instance, then it would be easy to rename SiteCustomerRelationship as a Contract. In that context it makes perfect sense for Contract to be its own entity, and have the the model look like Vendor-Contract-Customer-Office.

There are other ways to look at this as well. Udi has a decent post on this sort of many-to-many relationship [here](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/01/24/ddd-many-to-many-object-relational-mapping/).

Comment: In my actual model it is called a Terminal (what the domain experts call it), I renamed it Site because I thought it would be LESS confusing.  FAIL.  You can think of it as a Branch Location of our company.

Comment: Renaming it as a contract would be ok except contracts are already entities in the system as they have a slightly different meaning to our users. This is honestly the best name I could come up with.

Comment: Gah! Its exactly the part that Udi glosses over in the second to last section that I need. Should I refactor to bounded contexts? I haven't read that part of the book yet!

Comment: Is the CustomerSiteRelationship an Account then? What are they doing at your site that makes the relationship necessary to capture in the model?

Comment: They store products at our Terminals. This might imply the presence of a contract (user sense of the word). Relationships can be enabled/disabled meaning the customer cannot store product there any more. There are also defaults set up for a customer-terminal and applied on transactions between them.

Comment: It looks more and more like a permission thing then. Analogous to Users-Permissions-Actions. In a user account scenario, there may be X security actions a user can take, and for each user they have a permission to that action. Here, your customers can store... or not (plus related metadata).

Comment: Hmm maybe, do you know somewhere where how to handle this is discussed in depth?

Comment: The DDD Group on Yahoo: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/domaindrivendesign/messages

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a object Like SiteCustomerRelationship, its DB specific.

If its truly DDD you should have a Relation like:

```
Aggregate<Site> Customer.Site
IEnumerable<Aggregate<Office>> Customer.Offices
```

and perhaps

```
Aggregate<Office> Customer.DefaultOffice
```

Comment: It is a Relationship, not a relation (which would be DB specific).  The Relationship itself has properties (such as whether it is active, default settings and default office). A husband and wife can have a Relationship/Marriage that would be an object too (length of marriage, number of kids, etc.)

Comment: My point is that is it the relationship that is active/inactive or is it the customer. It woul make a much simpler model if those where attributes of customer instead of having a "meta data" entity between them

Comment: It is the relationship that is inactive. That's what I'm saying by the Marriage example.  If building a husband-wife domain it is reasonable for a Marriage to be an object. My SiteCustomerRelationship is an object in the same exact sense. There might be a different name for it later..